# RegEx to find all the file with a specific patter

Tags: regex

I'm new on the regex and I'm trying to find all the files inside some folders.
The files name are like this:
B11102R-300x1608.jpg
AT5020.jpg
AT5045-1-1024x1024.jpg
ABBIGLIAMENTO-324x130.jpg
etc...

What I would like to is find all the files that have the images size append to it... so I'm trying to create a regex to show only file that contains this pattern -300x1608.jpg where of course the numbers are random.

I tried with this regex -(.*?). but it doesn't solve the problem since it select from the first - and thus it can find similar false positive match!

Could you help me?
regards,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force a search for numbers:

```
^.*-\d+x\d+\.jpg$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYc5F4/5).

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `.*` - Any character other than newline zero or more times.
- `-` - A literal hyphen.
- `\d+x\d+` - At least a single digit, a literal x and again at least a single digit.
- `\.` - A literal dot (need to be escaped).
- `jpg` - Literally match 'jpg'.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Comment: Hello JvdV thanks a lot for the quick reply... you made my day. Could you please help me understand the expression better? I see ^.* and I think it means everything that come before than (and here is where the magic happen) there is -\d+x\d+\. so you tell to find any number between - and . but with the simbol x between is it right? I could not undeerstand the meanings of the $ at the end. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LCCA, sure thing, see the edit for some explaination.